# Where is the gtk# widget for windows forms in mono?

Tags: application-development, mono

I downloaded mono to program in c#. The installation worked fine and I have mono up and running. The problem is, I can't find the toolbox that contains stuff like:

```
Common controls
containers Menus and toolbars
All Windows Forms
```

This is for the visual design part! I cant find them!

I also can't see the window to work on. (By default its called "Form1")

I'm trying to get mono to look like this:

[image]

See, the window in the middle called "MainWindow" I can't see that in mono. Also, on the top right, I cant find that widget box!

Answer (score 1):

Mono has two GUI frontends, winforms and gtk#. Winform is the traditional method in windows and Visual Studio. Mono develop does not have a GUI designer for winforms yet.

An alternate method is using gtk binding for mono called [gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp). It has a GUI designer as shown in your question:

[image]